# TypeError: split() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have looked at the questions similar, but they are all for user defined functions. Mine is using the default .split() function.

The answers for the other questions indicate that I am missing a "self" argument, but I don't see how I can implement for this case.

My code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

def filterBlankImages(maskInputPath, maskOutputPath, imgType = '.jpg', imgInputPath = "Same", imgOutputPath = "Same"):
    if imgInputPath == "Same":
        imgInputPath = maskInputPath
    if imgOutputPath == "Same":
            imgOutputPath = maskOutputPath    
    for M1 in os.listdir(maskInputPath):
        if M1.endswith(".png"):
            M2 = Image.open(maskInputPath + M1)
            data = asarray(M2)
            data_sum = np.sum(data)
            if data_sum == 0:
                I1 = M2.split("_")[0]
                I2 = M2.split("_")[1].split("_cp")[0]
                I3 = I1 + '_' + I2 + imgType
                os.rename(imgInputPath + I3, imgOutputPath + I3)
                os.rename(maskInputPath + M1, maskOutputPath + M1)
```

The error I get:

```
File "/Users/msshah/Downloads/PreprocessingFunctions.py", line 74, in filterBlankImages
    I1 = M2.split("_")[0]

TypeError: split() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `M3 = M2.split('_')[0]` is not in your code sample

Comment: From the documentation available here - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.split , `.split()` indeed seems to take only 1 parameter, while you are providing 2 parameters (the `self` reference, which is automatically inserted, and the string '_'). You should most likely call the `.split()` method with no parameter at all.

Comment: Where is `M3 = M2.split('_')[0]` in your code?

Comment: are you mixing the string split with the [numpy split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)? M2 is not a string but the result of `Image.open()`, so you have to provide the necessary parameters to split the data of M2. But looking at your code it looks like you are treating M2 as a string

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thank you, it appears I posted the wrong code output.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thank you for pointing that out, I realize I should be using M1

Comment: Completely my fault, I was using the Image variable instead of the path variable. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: That's why you should never name your variables M1, M2... name them with descriptive names so it's clear what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M2` is a `PIL.Image` object. The [`PIL.Image.split()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.split) method takes no additional arguments (the implied argument being `self`, the `Image` in question.

You're thinking of [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), which takes in a separator and a maximum number of splits (if you want to specify a maximum).

Perhaps you meant to split `M1`?